# Electrical line distance vs phase shift

Tags: phase-shift

The below screenshot is from [TQP7M9104](https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/TQP7M9104) page-8. Note 8 provides the constraints on the distance between components. If I am not wrong, this is for electrical line distance to control the phase offset. I have two questions wrt this.

1. How can we actually calculate this phase shift for the placement of specific component? Any tool or any pointers to where I can learn?
2. This component is an amplifier and how did the manufacturer come at the number 9.2 deg, 21.8 deg, 14.7 deg, etc?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Enemra

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would call the distances "constraints".  Your picture is for an eval board that uses the TQP7M9104 amplifier.  And those phase shifts are what's determined from the component placement, trace length between components and the propagation velocity of the RF signal through those traces.

> How can we actually calculate this phase shift for the placement of specific component? Any tool or any pointers to where I can learn?

If you know the length, the frequency, and prop speed of the signal (determined by the Dk of the board material), you can calculate the phase shift.

> Any tool or any pointers to where I can learn

Given what I said above, it's a pretty simple calculation.  The tool that was used to design the PCB may have the capability to give you those parameters.  Also a tool like ADS will do that also.

> This component is an amplifier and how did the manufacturer come at the number 9.2 deg, 21.8 deg, 14.7 deg, etc?

Just like I described above.  Either they did the component placement first, then calculated the phase shifts.  Or the phase shifts were a requirment (a given), and so they adjusted the layout, component placement, and trace routing to give the required phase shifts.